# Creating a hyperlink in GWT TreeItem

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt

I am attempting to create a hyperlink in a `TreeItem`. I want to open another widget on click of this link. Following is my code:

```
Anchor partName = new Anchor();
partName.setText(CommonUtils.trim(circuitPartDetailsTO.getPartTO().getName(), 30));              
partName.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
        PartValueDisplayPopupWidget partValueDisplayPopupWidget = new PartValueDisplayPopupWidget(circuitPartDetailsTO.getPartTO().getPartId());
        partValueDisplayPopupWidget.center();
        DepthERP.eventBus.fireEvent(new PartDetailsPopupEvent(circuitPartDetailsTO.getPartTO().getPartId()));
    }
});
sb.append(partName);
HTML partRow = new HTML(sb.toString());
TreeItem tNdePart = new TreeItem(partRow);
```

`sb` is of type StringBuffer.

In the resultant output, the hyperlink appears but the `onClick` event handler does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Your solution is not going to work, because you pass a plain HTML string to your TreeItem. It contains no information on any handlers.

Instead, you can add a SelectionHandler to your Tree, and move your code from onClick to onSelection method. You can also make your TreeItem look like a link, if you want, by applying CSS styles.